# Scrollbar arrow is not being visually animated when I use InvalidateRect()

Tags: c, winapi

I have created an horizontal Scrollbar control, I have the following code in the `WM_HSCROLL` event handler:

```
case WM_HSCROLL:
    {
        InvalidateRect(hWnd, NULL, TRUE);
    }
    break;
```

When I remove `InvalidateRect()` and click on the arrow button, it gets animated as expected:

[image]

However, when I use `InvalidateRect()`, the arrow button does not get animated when clicked:

[image]

This is the code I have for `WM_PAINT`:

```
case WM_PAINT:
    {
        PAINTSTRUCT ps;
        HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);

        EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
    }
    break;
```

Answer (score 1):

I think I know what the problem is:

- When `InvalidateRect()` is called, it will send a `WM_PAINT` message to the
  parent Window **as well to the child controls**.
- Now when I click on the arrow button, the event handler for the arrow
  button click will be executed, I suppose it will animate the arrow button. However, the `WM_PAINT`
  message from `InvalidateRect()` will redraw the Scrollbar (to its original un-animated state), and hence the animation will
  not be noticeable.

To fix this problem, just use the `WS_CLIPCHILDREN` style when creating the parent Window, now when `InvalidateRect()` is called it will only send a `WM_PAINT` message to the parent Window and not to the child controls.

**Note:** I don't know if there is any disadvantage of using `WS_CLIPCHILDREN`.